# vue.js - How to import route components from external files

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm going through this page in the vue.js documentation: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html

The example javascript given starts by defining the route components:

```
// 1. Define route components.
// These can be imported from other files
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }
```

Concerning the second comment `These can be imported from other files` - how exactly can route components be imported from other files? Are there any good examples of how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

**Foo.js**

```
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
export default Foo
```

**Bar.js**

```
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }
export default Bar
```

**Routes.js**

```
import Foo from "./Foo"
import Bar from "./Bar"

const routes = [
  { path: "/foo", component: Foo },
  { path: "/bar", component: Bar }
]
```

Comment: Coming back to this, I've stored my external file in folder `routes`, and unfortunately `import Foo from "routes/Foo"` doesn't work, nor does `"routes/foo.js"`.

Comment: @rpivovar  `import Foo from "./routes/Foo"` ?